# New to Magento, any open sourced plugin themes?

Tags: magento

Just got thru watching a few videos about the way themes are handled by checking locations you specify in the backend, but they always fall back on default css/js.  I'm wondering if there are any good communities that build simple themes for magento that wouldn't require much more than dropping a folder into the magento_root/skin/ folder.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are a lot of free and paid themes for magento, take a look @

http://www.templatemonster.com/magento-themes.php

http://web-experiment.info/

http://www.mage-world.com/magento-themes.html

Answer (score 1):

You can check out Free theme section -

http://www.magikcommerce.com/free